# Evaluating property equality in Nant

Tags: build-process, nant

In my Nant script I would like to compare a property value to a known string. After reading the [Nant Expressions](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc1/help/fundamentals/expressions.html#op-string-equal) documentation I believed I would be able to do a basic '==' comparison to evaluate as a boolean.

However given the script block:

```
<if test="${target.env} == Dev">
  <echo message="***** You are using DEV"/>
</if>
```

When executed I recieve the following error:

```
'Dev == Dev' is not a valid value for attribute 'test' of <if ... />.
    Cannot resolve 'Dev == Dev' to boolean value.
    String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
```

This seems as though it should be simple (and probably is). How do I compare two strings, or properties in Nant to evaluate as a boolean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [here](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/if.html) for example. e.g.

```
<if test="${target.env}=='Dev'">
    ....
</if>
```

Comment: beautiful. i knew it would be easy!

Comment: For me this is what worked <if test="${target.env=='Dev'}">

Answer (score 18):

It also works if you have the entire expression within the curly braces:

```
<if test="${target.env =='Dev'}">
    ....
</if>
```

Comment: This way also works if you're comparing to an empty string (e.g. <if test="${target.env == ''}"> ), where-as the top version doesn't

Answer (score 5):

if you want to compare two variables ${test.var1} and ${test.var2}
then

```
<if test="${test.var1 == test.var2}">
....
</if>
```